# Script MikroTik For Search Contains of Strings

Tags: mikrotik

I have queue tree name **int-up_bw_duyungoffice** and **int-down_bw_duyungoffice**. Can i grep the words **duyungoffice** in MikroTik CLI? So the print result is information for int-***up***_bw_duyungoffice and int-***down***_bw_duyungoffice.

Default script that i know just like below:

```
> queue tree print where name=int-down_bw_duyungoffice
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid     
 0   name="int-down_bw_duyungoffice" 
     parent=TOTAL INTL DOWN - 1Mbps - Blok 1 (1:16) 
     packet-mark=packet-down_bw_duyungoffice limit-at=64k 
     queue=pcq-down-client-1Mbps(1:16) priority=8 max-limit=1M burst-limit=0 
     burst-threshold=0 burst-time=0s
```

But that script only shows int-down_bw_duyungoffice only.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to grep from the output above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. use `~` like this:

```
queue tree print where name~"duyungoffice"
```